# Reliable test for intersection of two Bezier curves

Tags: computational-geometry, intersection, bezier

How to reliably find out whether two Bezier curves intersect? By "reliably" I mean the test will answer "yes" only when the curves intersect, and "no" only when they don't intersect. I don't need to know what parameters the intersection was found at. I also would like to use floating-point numbers in the implementation.

I found several answers here which use the curves' bounding-boxes for the test: this is not what I'm after as such test may report intersection even if the curves don't intersect.

The closest thing I found so far is the "bounding wedge" by Sederberg and Meyers but it "only" distinguishes between at-most-one and two-or-more intersection, whereas I want to know if there is at-most-zero and one-or-more intersections.

Comment: you use the bounding box method to find out if they *don't* intersect. If there is bbox overlap, you're not done yet, now you need to actually find the intersections, because until you do, you can't tell whether there is an intersection due to how their maths works.

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming *cubic* bezier curves.

The most reliable method for reporting intersections, using floating point computation, is probably to *find* them, combined with *error analysis*.

The main problem, when floating point computations are involved, is inconsistency in computed results w.r.t. topology. Unfortunately this is unavoidable, if you need to compute anything in computational geometry within a *reasonable* amount of time.

So instead of stressing on the right algorithm for intersection calculation, picking a simple one and implementing error analysis is probably the solution.

I would try to implement an efficient subdivision algorithm like bezier-clipping (or a variant of quadratic clipping –[Nicholas North's Geo-clip](http://scholarsarchive.byu.edu/etd/1207/)), and with running error analysis to compute tight error bounds so that we don't "miss" intersections.

To elaborate, The *main* sources of floating-point (double prec.) error in these subdivision based algorithms are:

1. Truncation error: especially the error in the input coefficients etc. which are also finite —we can't do much here within the algorithm.
2. Roundoff error during De Casteljau subdivision and point evaluation.

I have used the running error bounds for De Casteljau's algorithm —[explained here](http://scholarsarchive.byu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=5245&context=etd), along with Geo-clip algorithm. It is fast and robust. (B.t.w. This theses, in general, is a good read if you want to make polynomial/bezier algorithms more robust)

Assuming, you know the basics of the [bezier clipping algorithm](http://nishitalab.org/user/nis/cdrom/cad/CAGD90Curve.pdf), the general idea is to expand the *hybrid bezier curve* (in the first paper linked) and the *fat line* appropriately with the error bounds for each clip.

Some other unrelated ideas:

- You can try a variant of Bentley-Ottmann sweepline algorithm. First you have to split the bezier curves as X monotone segments; and look at their Y orderings as you sweep across them. This method has a few disadvantages, since bezier curves are also capable of intersecting with multiplicity of more than one - think of tangential intersection. Doing an error analysis may be difficult here (when you compute a y value, there is some floating point error involved)
- Interval Projected Polyhedron algorithm: This uses *rounded interval arithmetic* for robustness. But the algorithm for 2D Bezier curves gets quite [complicated](http://web.mit.edu/hyperbook/Patrikalakis-Maekawa-Cho/node42.html)

There are a few cases you might come across:

1. Self intersections
2. Overlapping (coincident) curves: Subdivision algorithms will keep going in this case. This can be *easy* [to check](http://web.mit.edu/hyperbook/Patrikalakis-Maekawa-Cho/node111.html) though.

Good luck :)

Comment: Don't forget that if the purpose here is for purely visual intersection, a far simpler solution is to just compare the curve LUTs, because then we're not looking for the "true" intersection, but only for whether a human would claim there is one based on what they see.

Comment: Do you perhaps know of any implementation of Geo-clip?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming cubic beziers, the intersection points are real roots of a 9th degree polynomial. The existence of such roots within an interval (from negative to positive infinity for infinitely long curves, or 0 to 1 for your typical piecewise cubic beziers) can be checked robustly using a [Sturm sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem). This will only work if we allow extending one of the curves to infinity. The algorithm will have no loops, and only use basic arithmetic operations (add, subtract and multiply, while division should be avoidable).

For maximum robustness, you could use arbitrary precision math. Since the number of steps is constant, the maximum possible number of digits in all temporary results is bounded. That way, your algorithm will always return the correct result, no matter how pathological the input (eg. curves barely touching).

It might be possible to use ordinary floating point first, and detect potential pathological cases (intermediate results becoming zero, when adding/subtracting previous intermediate results).

The formulas for getting the polynomial terms from Bezier control points are truly a sight to behold, but luckily you don't have to work them out,
 they're [right here on Github](https://github.com/thelonious/kld-intersections/blob/0f0aecea6923c0042c72f514fa914cac95a72686/lib/Intersection.js#L621-L709).

There's a thread from 2004, [Closed-form of Bezier intersection test](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.graphics.algorithms/sZP2StzNmjk/nsLt9GyS9dEJ) on `comp.graphics.algorithms` with more details.

If you're dealing with quadratic beziers, the polynomial will only be 4th degree.

Answer (score 0):

An idea from the top of my head.
Map them, so they are in the same domain, such that you can subtract them. Then just do a root finding. There are lots and lots of numeric methods to root finding.

Comment: Unfortunately, that "map them" part isn't actually possible: they're not plain functions, they're parametric curves with independent control variables, so without first reparameterizing the curves (which is an incredibly hard problem) no such mapping can be done.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to see if two curves intersect **visually**, say real-time screen graphics in a game or something, then the easiest way to do so, *by far*, is to simply compare their pixels.

Get the bbox and pixel lookup tables (LUTs) for both curves, check if there's bbox overlap: no overlap? done. There is no intersection. Overlap? sort the LUTs with a fast sorter, and then just run a compare. The moment you find a single match, you're done. There is an overlap, and you don't care where.

If you have to do this for lots of curves: use a library that does this for you, don't waste your time implementing it yourself, you're not going to be as efficient (for large collections things like oct-trees and scanline checks become far more efficient)

However, if you need to know if there is **absolute, mathematically precise** overlap, say for as-correct-as-possible design work, then you can't cut corners: actually run a real intersection detection algorithm to find all possible intersection points. Real-time is mostly irrelevant in this setting, you can spend the few more cycles to run a proper detection algorithm.